# Counting occurrences of word in a text

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity

Let's say I have a long text of 1M words and I would like to create a table of all the words ordered by the number of occurrences in the text.

One approach would be populating a dynamic array with each word and linear search them to count the occurrences in $O(n^2)$ then sort the array by occurrences in $O(n \log n)$.

Another approach would be to use y priority queue and a trie. The insertion in the priority queue is $O(\log n)$ and the build of the trie is $O(n)$. But traversing the trie to build the priority queue is somehow difficult to evaluate.

Eventually using a hash map seems to be the best solution, but computing the hash could cost a little bit of time even though it is just a constant. In this you have $n$ insertion/lookup in $O(1)$ then a final sort of the hashmap by occurrences in $O(n \log n)$.

So it is clear that the former approach is the worse and the latter the best. But how can I evaluate the complexity of the second one?

Comment: This looks a lot like this previous question: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/26427/word-frequency-with-ordering-in-on-complexity.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand why do you need a priority queue.

The best algorithm should be as follows (pseudocode):

```
1) count the words
2) sort them by count
```

Counting each word you can loop through each word and update the count in the hash table for each word.    This is done $n$ times and you need $O(1)$ for accessing + $O(1)$ updating the hash table thus $O(n)$.

Sorting is $O(n \log n)$. Thus the complexity is $O(n \log n)$.